# Diccionarios, claves y valores en python

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo una duda sobre diccionarios en python

Es posible hacer que un valor que ingrese un usuario, el computador busque en un diccionario y muestre sus valores. Es decir se puede hacer que una varibale input sea igual a una clave en un diccionario para mostrar sus valores?

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
diccionario = {
"0000 0000 00001": ["Jose J", 26],
"0000 0000 00002": ["Paulino P"],
}
```

Ahora lo que quiero que pase es que el usuario para identificarse ingrese un dato, pero quiero que ese dato si es igual la clave, por ejemplo que el usuario ingrese 0000 0000 00001, entonces el programa muestre los valores Jose J y 26.

Es posible? Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: a que te refieres si puedes acceder por esa llave.. si puedes `diccionario["0000 0000 00001"]`

Comment: Por decirlo así, el diccionario es mi base de datos. Lo que yo quiero hacer es acceder a los valores que tiene cada clave, pero no quiero que sea yo directamente sino el usuario. Por ejemplo que el ponga el valor de una clave, entonces se muestren los valores.

Comment: te refierfes a :`''.join(map(str ,diccionario["0000 0000 00001"])`

Comment: `k=input("Clave? "); print(diccionario[k])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes una posible solución, recorriendo el diccionario y comparando las claves de cada iteración con la clave que estés buscando, en este caso la del ejemplo que tú mismo has descrito.

```
diccionario = {
"0000 0000 00001": ["Jose J", 26],
"0000 0000 00002": ["Paulino P"],
}

for clave in diccionario:
    if clave == "0000 0000 00001":
        print(diccionario[clave]);
        break
```

Comment: Los diccionarios están diseñados específicamente para poder encontrar un dato sin tener que recorrerlos. Hacer un bucle para ir comparando hasta encontrar la clave va en contra de su razón de existir.

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenidx rockyprogrammer c:

Recorrer el diccionario con un bucle e ir comparando las claves hasta encontrar la correcta, además de ser un método innecesariamente complejo, es más lento.

Cito comentario de @Abulafia:

> Los diccionarios están diseñados específicamente para poder encontrar
> un dato sin tener que recorrerlos. Hacer un bucle para ir comparando
> hasta encontrar la clave va en contra de su razón de existir.

En lugar de recorrer el diccionario, puedes poner la clave entre corchetes al lado del diccionario para acceder al valor. Por ejemplo:

```
print(diccionario["0000 0000 00002"])
```

Produce:

```
["Paulino P"]
```

---

Yo considero que la forma más eficiente, rápida y simple de hacer lo que buscas (la cual ya fue mencionada por Abulafia en los comentarios) es:

```
# Pido al usuario la clave
clave = input("clave: ")

# Obtengo el valor asociado a la clave
print(diccionario[clave])
```